# CombineReducers fucntion with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use context API and not redux so I'm coming across this problem when trying to combine the reducers together. Here is the code:

```
const mainReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: AppMenuActions | AuthActions | LayoutActions) => ({
    appMenu: AppMenuReducer(state.appMenu, action),
    auth: AuthReducer(state.auth, action),
    layout: LayoutReducer(state.layout, action),
});
```

it works fine if there is no type but I'm using typescripts so each of my reducer take in an action type according to that reducer either AppMenuActions or AuthActions or LayoutActions. Because I dont know at the time of using which action I will be passing in so I have to use the unions | for the action arg of mainReducer. When i pass in that action to each of the reducer typescript complain because forexample AppMenuReducer action only take in the type AppMenuActions but being pass in AppMenuActions | AuthActions | LayoutActions. I'm stuck dont know how to solve this. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the typescript documentation turned out it could be done by type assertion and in this case I would use:

```
const mainReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: AppMenuActions | AuthActions | LayoutActions) => ({
    appMenu: AppMenuReducer(state.appMenu, action as AppMenuActions),
    auth: AuthReducer(state.auth, action as AuthActions),
    layout: LayoutReducer(state.layout, action as LayoutActions),
});
```